# NameError states that dictionary does not exist, but it does exist

Tags: python, numpy, list-comprehension, nameerror

A dictionary named `ctl_exp_info` exists in the Variable Explorer in Spyder, as does a list of channel names

```
chsort = 
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24']
```

In debug mode, the following statements work:

```
for ch in chsort:
    print(np.array([ctl_exp_info[sensor][ch][0][0]]]))
```

But the list comprehension version throws a `NameError`:

```
srm = np.array([ctl_exp_info[sensor][ch][0][0] for ch in chsort])
*** NameError: name 'ctl_exp_info' is not defined
```

I have not mistyped a '1' for an 'l' anywhere.

If I look at the results of `dir()`, `ctl_exp_info` appears in the namespace.
Any idea why this occurs, and how to fix it?

Python 3.6.5 on Windows, Spyder 3.2.8.

Comment: Hello Bill, and welcome to Stack Overflow! In the future, please format your code using backticks: \`this\` becomes `this` which looks a lot nicer. I got an edit to your question pending to do this; just something to know in the future. Thanks, and good luck with your question!

Comment: Is this code cut and pasted from your script, or did you retype it?

Comment: hard to help without a [mcve]... If it says it doesn't exist, it's because it doesn't. You are probably trying to run that line in a different session / console / kernel than the one where it is defined...

Comment: mind checking whether its present in `locals()` or `globals()` or `vars()`